# Is it good to skip ASP.NET and jump into ASP.NET MVC directly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a desktop app developer, I wanted to study web programming.  Is it good to skip ASP.NET and jump into ASP.NET MVC directly?  My last experience with web is with PHP, circa 2000

And also, is ASP.NET MVC enterprise-ready(think desktop apps with rich user experience) in terms of components support (be it open-source or commercial ones) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is based on ASP.NET so if you know ASP.NET it will be a plus but in my opinion it is not necessary. If your last experience with the web is with PHP in 2000 you should be aware that many things have changed since. ASP.NET MVC is not as mature as WebForms so in terms of components support there's much less. This doesn't mean that you won't be able to develop rich internet applications it's just that there are less components out of the box.